# How to Autofill Down (dynamic range) with a different array of data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in C2:K11 that I need to autofill down to the next row with data.

[image: As you can see here]

This is what i was able to use successfully to this point, the only problem is it is copying to an assigned range i.e. C13:K22 rather than filling in all of the cells.

```
Sub CopyStandardFacilitiesDown() 
Sheets("Facilities").Range("C3:K12").Copy 
Range("C13:K22").Select 'Last used cell in column c 
Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ActiveSheet.Paste Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End Sub
```

When I try to use a dynamic range via the following, I am only able to copy one cell down rather than copying my entire range to all other cells.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AY2:AY" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) 
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Ideally C3:K11 would get copie and applied to each "Org Name"

Here is a picture of the desired end result

[image]

Comment: So, there is some formula in cell (let's say) C12 that you want to autofill down, right?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that?

```
Sub autofilldown()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Facilities") 'instead of Active.Workbook you should use the name of the workbook you are working on

Dim LR As Long 'LR stands for last row
LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'it will autofill down as long as there is something in corresponding cell in column B
   With ws
      .Range("C12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C12:C" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
      .Range("D12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("D12:D" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
      .Range("E12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("E12:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
      .Range("F12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F12:F" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
      .Range("G12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("G12:G" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
      .Range("H12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("H12:H" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
      .Range("I12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("I12:I" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
      .Range("J12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("J12:J" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
      .Range("K12").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("K12:K" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
   End With
End Sub
```

This should autofill formulas you have in row 12 down till the last nonempty cell in column B.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, I need to copy all of the data in the range C3:K12 and copy all of those cells down rather than just row 12. Is there a way to replace your reference cell with a reference range to copy down? I have found several resources but cant seem to fit it to my application.  Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!